# Use uniq on hash of arrays

Tags: ruby, hash

Given a hash of arrays:

```
a =
{:b => [:x, :x, :y], :c => [:x, :z, :z]}
```

I would like to remove all duplicates from the arrays in the hash.

Expected result:

```
a
# => {:b => [:x, :y], :c => [:x, :z]}
```

What does not work:

```
a.each { |e| e.uniq! }
```

Neither does:

```
a.each { |e| e = e.uniq } # should be the same as above, really
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A hash consists of _pairs_, so `each` yields _two_ values: `a.each { |k, v| v.uniq! }` or alternatively `a.each_value(&:uniq!)`

Comment: BTW, `a.each { |e| e = e.uniq }` is **not** the same as `a.each { |e| e.uniq! }` – the assignment in the former one doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Stefan, I made a beginner's mistake in perusing hashes that I should have seen myself ;-) Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Hash#transform_values**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)

```
a.transform_values(&:uniq) #=> {:b=>[:x, :y], :c=>[:x, :z]}
```

or `transform_values!` to modify in-place. Both methods require Ruby >= 2.4.

[**Array#map**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map)

Use `map` for Ruby < 2.4.

```
a.map { |k,arr| [k,arr.uniq] }.to_h #=> {:b=>[:x, :y], :c=>[:x, :z]}
```

Comment: Why is `map` "safer"?

Comment: @Stefan I think it's acceptable usage, to mean it will work across more versions of Ruby. But yes it could be misconstrued.

Comment: @Cary Okey dokey, best to be clear so I've made the edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new array for each hash value, then @SagarPandya's answer will work, but you can also do an in-place modification to the array.

```
a = {:b => [:x, :x, :y], :c => [:x, :z, :z]}

a.each_value(&:uniq!) # => {:b=>[:x, :y], :c=>[:x, :z]}
a # => {:b=>[:x, :y], :c=>[:x, :z]}
```

Comment: I really had a hard time deciding whom to give credits for the accepted answer. Finally went with @sagar-pandya's as it was the first and simplest and (after the edit) also a very comprehensive one. Would not want to disregard yours though. Thanks.